# How do you use Xcode 5 to create a key for use in signing Java application?

Tags: java, xcode, codesign

My Java application is signed as follows

```
/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX --requirements "=designated => anchor apple generic and identifier \"com.jthink.jaikoz\" and ((cert leaf[field.1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.9] exists) or ( certificate 1[field.1.2.840.113635.100.6.2.6] exists and certificate leaf[field.1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.13] exists and certificate leaf[subject.OU] = \"9VEBH439W3\" ))" /Applications/Jaikoz.app
```

but it no longer works gives a warning

```
/Applications/Jaikoz.app: code object is not signed at all
In subcomponent: /Applications/Jaikoz.app/Contents/PlugIns/jdk1.7.0_40.jdk
./buildosx.sh: line 16: --/usr/bin/codesign: No such file or directory
```

since updating to Mavericks and installing Xcode 5.0.1

So I wonder if I have to regenerate the key.
Previously I followed some instructions for creating an app in Xcode, building and copying some build output but I cant find the build output to copy, anyone point me in te right direction please.

Comment: It is a terminal comment, so my plan was to use Xcode to redo the part that gives me the XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX part in the first place as I believe it must have changed as a result of upgrading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I now have to use the `--deep` option

I also figured out that I can just refer to ceritificate by name

e.g.

```
    export CODESIGN_ALLOCATE="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate"
    /usr/bin/codesign --deep  --force --sign "Developer ID Application: P Taylor" /Applications/Jaikoz.app
    /usr/bin/codesign --deep -v /Applications/Jaikoz.app
```